# How to attach a weapon to players hand and implement dynamic aiming?

Tags: libgdx, 2d, game-engine, lwjgl, game-development

I wanted the weapon to be pointing in the direction of wherever the mouse is,[![This is my player texture][1]][1]

what i want is, if a weapon is in players hand, than the weapon along with the hand, being in perfect sync with the body points in the direction where ever the mouse is

I have no idea how to implement this mechanism, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off it completely depends on how the character is rigged. Are you using Spriter or something to that effect to produce a 2d skeletal animation rig? If so then the IK from that should take care of a weapon if you just attach it to the handbone. If not then simple trig is going to be your friend. Get the angle of the mouse to the center of the character or character's hand and then cos with be your X position for the weapon and sin will be your Y position.

Comment: Rotation is fine but How would you sync the hand texture with player body?also positioning it is the tough part

Comment: Again, if you are using skeletal animation then you would just add a hand bone to your rig which is connected to the arms. In program you would each frame get the position and rotation of that bone in world coordinates and move / rotate your sword sprite to those coordinates. If you are not using skeletal animation then IMO you are causing yourself more struggle trying to add in features like this than needed. Check out Spriter or Spine (2 most used skeletal anim frameworks) to do it yourself or I am pretty sure both Unity and Unreal Engine have 2D skeletal animation capabilities.

Comment: Additionally if you were hellbent on just using static sprites for the most part then you would basically need to open up your image editor, figure out what local coordinates the hand is at for each frame and then in your animation data include a vector2 for the weapon offset per frame to attach the sword to each frame.